# What is the rule when adding two (2x2) matrices without like terms?

Tags: matrices, education

So given two matrices of 2x2 and adding them together;

Since i am new here and i don't quite know how to format this properly you will just have to try to imagine these are placed in a 2x2 square.

So say from top left to bottom right i have in the first matrices the values 1,3,4,5 and in the second i have the values -2,3,2,a.

Given these two matrices what is the rule when it comes to adding the 5 and the a which are not like terms?

Would the sum of these matrices simply be;

-1,6,6,(5+a)?

Or is it not possible to add them because they do not share like terms?

Comment: Yes, that’s how you would do it.

Comment: Assuming the expression "$5+a$" makes sense, what you say is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much i just was not sure if the matrices was invalid because they were not like terms but my initial thoughts where it would be 5 + a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add two $n\times n$ square matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 3 \\ 2 & a \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 6 \\ 6 & 5+a \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Awesome thanks for this il figure out a way to put the problem as solved.

Comment: in fact, you can add any two matrices if they have the same size.